# Can I Deserialise JSON arrays of arrays in C#

Tags: json, json.net

I have a json something like. How could I deserialise into POCO. The automated class generation generated `public List<List<List<object>>> sseq {get;set;}`. With the leaf content coming as string, e.g

```
{
  "sn": "1 a",
  "dt": [["text", "{bc}a short brisk leap especially on one leg"]]
}
```

Is there a way to deserialise it using POCO? I am using Newtonsoft for deserialisation.

```json
{
  "sseq": [
    [
      [
        "sense",
        {
          "sn": "1 a",
          "dt": [["text", "{bc}a short brisk leap especially on one leg"]]
        }
      ],
      [
        "sense",
        {
          "sn": "b",
          "dt": [
            ["text", "{bc}{sx|bounce||}, {sx|rebound||} "],
            [
              "vis",
              [{ "t": "shortstop scooped it up on the first {wi}hop{\/wi}" }]
            ]
          ]
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        "sense",
        {
          "sn": "2",
          "dt": [["text", "{bc}{sx|dance||3}"]]
        }
      ]
    ],
    [
      [
        "sense",
        {
          "sn": "3 a",
          "dt": [["text", "{bc}a flight in an aircraft"]]
        }
      ],
      [
        "sense",
        {
          "sn": "b",
          "dt": [["text", "{bc}a short trip"]]
        }
      ]
    ]
  ]
}
```

UPDATE:
Corrected the example string at the leaf of deserialised POCO

Comment: I get something very different from `List<List<List<object>>> sseq` using https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp: see https://app.quicktype.io?share=36efCjlAvPd54SfquStw.  Anyway, what exactly is the problem?  `List<List<List<object>>>` is, strictly speaking, a POCO, so what do you need instead?  The items in the `"dt"` child arrays are sometimes strings (`"text"` e.g.) but sometimes objects (`{ "t": "shortstop scooped it up on the first {wi}hop{\/wi}" }` e.g.) so at some level your data model will need jagged 2d `object` collections.

Comment: I did not know about quicktype. The tool that I picked to generate the C# classes was obviously not up to mark, at I had to write the convertors myself. @dbc you have saved lot of my time it seems. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use Newtonsoft by using DeserializeObject.

We assume your model class is:

```
public class MyObjectClass
{
    public List<List<List<object>>> sseq { get; set; }
}
```

Than pass your data to DeserializeObject like this

```
var myObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObjectClass>(data);
```

That is it.